# The difference between Spin() and SpinOnce()

Tags: ros, spinonce, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone tell me the difference between Spin() and SpinOnce()? And what exactly they are doing, is it like a while loop to process some ROS stuff?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188595/the-difference-between-spin()-and-spinonce()./) by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-08-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-01**:
Thank you Stefan and tfoote.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-04**:
Next time try to ask your whole question in the title of the question, it will be shorter

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-04**:
Ok. Thanks.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
It was a joke!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is covered in the ROS Overview in the [Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) section.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both calls trigger the processing of callbacks. [Chapter 3](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/agitr-letter-pubsub.pdf) of the new [A gentle Introduction to ROS](http://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/) book does a good job at explaining this.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8